# SignalR persist connections for anonymous users

Tags: c#, signalr, session-cookies, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a SignalR Chat that is available to anonymous users. I need a way to map the users so that the connections persist on page reload, and if the user has multiple tabs they should get the message displayed on every tab.

If I use `Context.ConnectionId`, every page reload creates a new connection. I want to map these connections using **Single-user groups.**

For logged-in users, I use `Context.User.Identity.Name`:

```
Groups.AddAsync(Context.ConnectionId, Context.User.Identity.Name);
```

Is there a similar way to get an **anonymous user's "identity"**? From what I have read, session is not supposed to be used in the SignalR hub, but all the information I found is old, so I may be wrong here.

Comment: If you don't want them do identify themselves, that's ok. But you can assign them a name and save it as a cookie or session variable. You can also let them edit it.

Answer (score 1):

When you reload a page the existing connection will be closed and a new one will be opened. The new connection will have a new connection id and on the server side you will not be able to tell what user initiated it. Depending on your circumstances you could try identifying the user by their ip addresses - i.e. you would store the user ip when the connection is open and then, when a  new connection is opened you would check if you have already seen the ip. This may not work however because the same user can actually have different ips and multiple users can have the same ip. Another method would be to send a client side generated identifier in the query string when opening the connection and use that to identify the same user on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement some mechanism to create unique ID for each user.

I would do something like following

- Before user actually connects to Hub i would create a unique ID and
  store it in cookie
- set the query string for signalR URL with the value of this cookie so
  that each call to hub will avail with the user's ID
- now even when the user refreshes the page, the old connection would
  automatically get removed from the group by signalR and you can
  continue adding new connections mapped against the uniquely generated
  ID.